# LEFT JOIN to table once and get min and max values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, ssms

The basic concept of this question is that I need a query that gives me a distinct list of users and the dates we are looking for violations in. It shows the date and user regardless if there is a violation or not. The dates table outer applies to users to always show all dates for the user and if they have a violation on that date or not.
For Example:

```
UserID   Date    IsViolation
1         1/1      Y
1         1/2      Y
1         1/3      N
2         1/1      N
2         1/2      N
2         1/3      N
```

The problem is I need to join to a few tables to produce the violations for those users. So it is looking like this so far:

```
SELECT u.ID AS UserID,
   u.FirstName,
   u.LastName,
   uc.ClientName,
   ul.LocationName,
   d.Date
FROM dbo.User AS u
JOIN dbo.UserClient AS uc ON u.ID = uc.UserID
JOIN dbo.UserLocation AS ul ON u.ID = ul.userID
OUTER APPLY #Dates
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT uv.UserID,
               uv.ViolationID,
               uv.ViolationDate,
               v.ViolationName,
               vm.ViolationTypeID,
               uv.Date
            FROM dbo.UserViolation AS uv
            JOIN dbo.Violation AS v ON uv.ViolationID = v.ID
            JOIN dbo.ViolationMeta AS vm ON vm.ViolationID = v.ID
          ) AS v ON v.UserID = u.ID
             AND v.Date = d.Date
```

So now I will have a list of violations per date and user that looks something like this:

```
UserID Date ViolationTypeID
1      1/1       1
1      1/1       2
1      1/1       3
1      1/2       NULL
1      1/3       1
2      1/1       NULL
etc....
```

I need to group these into specific buckets based on the ViolationTypeID and ViolationID. So what I am thinking is to do something like below within the same query:

```
SELECT u.ID AS UserID,
   u.FirstName,
   u.LastName,
   uc.ClientName,
   ul.LocationName,
   d.Date,
   MAX(CASE WHEN v.ViolationID IN (1,2,3) AND [ViolationTypeID] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [FormViolation]
   MAX(CASE WHEN v.ViolationTypeID IN (5,6,7) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [UrgentViolaion]
   MIN(CASE WHEN v.ID IS NOT NULL AND v.ViolationTypeID IN (1,2,3) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS [NoViolation]
etc.....
GROUP BY u.ID,
       u.FirstName,
       u.LastName,
       uc.ClientName,
       ul.LocationName,
       d.Date
```

I am trying to hit the tables to produce the violations only once, instead of hitting them for each individual scenario in a separate joins to the tables. This seems a little convoluted right now to me, is there a simpler/more effective way to accomplish this?

Comment: Why do you need that subquery for your `LEFT OUTER JOIN`? Can't you just join to `UserViolation` since you're only checking the `UserID` and `ViolationDate` (I assume that's what you meant by `v.Date`)?

Comment: I added v.date to the subquery. I am doing that because not all users have violations, but I want to still show all users and days. I didn't want to continuously left join too all of the tables within the subquery by doing it in the main query, that's the reason its a subquery rather than left joining to all those tables.

Comment: Im not sure what is your question. Do you have a expected result?

Comment: The results would just be showing all users, all days, and if they have that type of violation on that day, as per the MIN MAX part of it. I only want 1 row per user per day, but joining to the violations without doing the MIN MAX logic gives me multiple rows as there is 1 user to many violations. The MIN/MAX is essentially taking the different types of violations and aggregating them into a yes or no for that day.

Comment: You really should get out of the habit of trying to organize your query in a way that **you** think will be most efficient for SQL. Write your query according to the logic that you need and let SQL Server worry about finding the best way to get the data. Otherwise you just end up hamstringing it. If you run into performance issues then you look at indexing, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For what I can tell, you want a `cross join` to get the users and dates.  Then a `left join` to violations and aggregation.  This is made a bit more complicated because the violations date is in `violations` rather than `userviolations` (that doesn't really make sense to me), but:

```
select u.id, d.date,
       (case when max(v.date) is null then 'N' else 'Y' end) as IsViolation
from dbo.User u cross join
     #dates d left join
     dbo.userviolation uv
     on u.id = uv.userid and
        d.date = uv.date
group by u.id, d.date;
```

Comment: You are correct, sorry that was a mistype, I added it to UserViolation,